# SCHED_OTHER : why min/max priority are both 0 ?

Tags: c, linux, scheduling

Question 1:

There are 140 priorities and SCHED_OTHER can have proprieties between 100 to 140.

But the chrt command gives SCHED_OTHER min/max priority    : 0/0 ! . I expected 100 to 140 (or 0 to 39). Why the priority is fixed as 0 ?

Question 2:

Is there any difference for SCHED_OTHER in O(1) and CFS in terns of priority level and nice value calculation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it here:

- sched_rt.c implements SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR semantics, in a simpler
  way than the vanilla scheduler does. It uses 100 runqueues (for all
  100 RT priority levels, instead of 140 in the vanilla scheduler)
  and it needs no expired array.